# Trigger Press Programmatically

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-component

I have following component

```
class LanguageScreen extends Component {

    _onPressButton() {

    }

    render() {
        var enButton = <RoundButton 
            buttonStyle={'black-bordered'}
            text={'EN'}
            locale={'en'}
            selected={true}
            style={styles.roundButtonStyle}
            onPress={this._onPressButton}
        />
        var arButton = <RoundButton
            buttonStyle={'golden-gradient'}
            text={'ع'}
            locale={'ar'}
            selected={false}
            style={styles.roundButtonStyle}
            onPress={this._onPressButton}
        />
        return(
            <View style={styles.rootViewStyle}>
                <View style={styles.buttonContainerRootViewStyle}>
                    <View style={styles.buttonContainerViewStyle}>
                        {enButton}
                        {arButton}
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.submitButtonContainerViewStyle}>
                    <Button style={styles.submitButtonStyle}/>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

When user press on enButton, I want to change the style of arButton and vice versa, to give you a picture, PFA below the screenshot.

[image]

Basically, I want to highlight one button at a time, lets say user click on EN, I want to highlight selected element and remove highlight from other.

This is my RoundButton component class

```
class RoundButton extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { isSelected: true === props.selected };
    }

    onClickListen = () => {
        this.setState({
            isSelected: !this.state.isSelected 
        });
        this.forceUpdate();
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.isSelected) {
            return this.goldenGradient(this.props);
        } else {
            return this.blackBordered(this.props)
        }   
    }

    goldenGradient(props) {
        return(
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.buttonStyle}
                onPress={this.props.onPress}
                onPressOut={this.onClickListen}
            >
                <LinearGradient
                    colors={['#E9E2B0', '#977743']}
                    start={{x: 1.0, y: 0.0}}
                    end={{x: 0.0, y: 1.0}}
                    style={styles.linearGradient}
                >
                    <Text style={this.props.locale == 'ar' ? styles.goldenGradientTextStyleAr : styles.goldenGradientTextStyle}>
                        {props.text}
                    </Text>
                </LinearGradient>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }

    blackBordered(props) {
        return(
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={
                    styles.buttonStyle,
                    styles.blackBorderedStyle
                }
                onPress={this.props.onPress}
                onPressOut={this.onClickListen}
            >
                <Text style={this.props.locale == 'ar' ? styles.blackBorderedTextStyleAr : styles.blackBorderedTextStyle}>
                    {props.text}
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }
}
```

The solution I was looking for was, If a user clicks on EN button, then I want other button also to trigger the press, this will cause the state to change and toggle the highlight status. No solution seems to be working. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution for this is let the father component manage the buttons highlight. So you have to put in the father component's state the current selected button, and pass a boolean prop to the button that indicates if it's selected or not. As I can see, your already pass a 'selected' prop, that prop should be handled in the father component, not in the button's one.

If you do as you said, you will interrupt the top-down data flow which react is based on

### UPDATE

#### Father component

Add constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    selectedButton: 'en'
  };

  this._onPressButton = this._onPressButton.bind(this); 
}
```

On button press:

```
_onPressButton(button) {
  this.setState({
    selectedButton: button
  });
}
```

Buttons init:

```
const arButton = <RoundButton
        buttonStyle={'golden-gradient'}
        text={'ع'}
        locale={'ar'}
        selected={this.checkButtonSelect('ar')}
        style={styles.roundButtonStyle}
        onPress={this._onPressButton}/>

const enButton = <RoundButton 
        buttonStyle={'black-bordered'}
        text={'EN'}
        locale={'en'}
        selected={this.checkButtonSelect('en')}
        style={styles.roundButtonStyle}
        onPress={this._onPressButton}
```

Check if button is selected

```
checkButtonSelect(button) {
  return this.state.selectedButton === button;
}
```

#### Button component

It pretty self explanatory

```
class RoundButton extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isSelected: true === props.selected };
}

onClickListen = () => {
    this.props.onPress(this.props.locale);

    /*
    * You dont need this, the component is already updated on setState()
    * call
    */
    //this.forceUpdate();
}

render() {
    if (this.state.isSelected) {
        return this.goldenGradient(this.props);
    } else {
        return this.blackBordered(this.props)
    }   
}

goldenGradient(props) {
    return(
        <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.buttonStyle}
            onPress={this.onClickListen}
        >
            <LinearGradient
                colors={['#E9E2B0', '#977743']}
                start={{x: 1.0, y: 0.0}}
                end={{x: 0.0, y: 1.0}}
                style={styles.linearGradient}
            >
                <Text style={this.props.locale == 'ar' ? styles.goldenGradientTextStyleAr : styles.goldenGradientTextStyle}>
                    {props.text}
                </Text>
            </LinearGradient>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}

blackBordered(props) {
    return(
        <TouchableOpacity
            style={
                styles.buttonStyle,
                styles.blackBorderedStyle
            }
            onPress={this.props.onPress}
            onPressOut={this.onClickListen}
        >
            <Text style={this.props.locale == 'ar' ? styles.blackBorderedTextStyleAr : styles.blackBorderedTextStyle}>
                {props.text}
            </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry I just started with react, can you help me on how to go about with the code?

Comment: I am getting the error, this.setState is not a function, not sure why.

Comment: You have to bind 'this' to the function in the constructor. Updated again

Comment: or you can bind it in-line: in your button init -> `onPress={this._onPressButton.bind(this)}`

Comment: Because you have to init your selectedButton. Updated again, check the constructor part

Comment: Now it shows no error, however only the initial state is set, when I click on the other button, it does not highlight.

Comment: Strange. Check if the onPress function is called or not by console.logging or debugger

Comment: I did the debug for `_onPressButton(button)` when I click on `EN` it shows the value `en` but when I click on the other button it shows `[object Object]` the value supposed to be show is `ar`

Comment: Pretty strange. In arButton locale is `locale={'ar'}`, so I really don't know why you getting ad object.. Maybe double brackets?

Comment: In RoundButton.js I was using `onPress` and `onPressOut` I removed `onPressOut` and just kept `onPress` now it seems to give the correct value, but the highlight still does not work.

Comment: what you'r getting now from `_onPressButton(button)`?

Comment: I get `en` and `ar` values based on selected button, this seems to be correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182851/discussion-between-ibrahim-azhar-armar-and-andriy-klitsuk).

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about changing the status in parent component where the buttons are rendered? Why don't you track which button was pressed in `LanguageScreen` and then pass this information to the buttons.

```
    _onPressButton (selectedLocale) {
      this.setState({ selectedLocale })
    }

    var enButton = <RoundButton 
        onPress={this._onPressButton}
        isSelected={this.state.selectedLocale === 'en'}
        ...youStaff
    />
    var arButton = <RoundButton
        onPress={this._onPressButton}
        isSelected={this.state.selectedLocale === 'ar'}
        ...yourStaff
    />
```

And in your `RoundButton`:

```
onClickListen = () => {
    this.props.onPress(this.props.locale)
}

render() {
    if (this.props.isSelected) {
        return this.goldenGradient(this.props);
    } else {
        return this.blackBordered(this.props)
    }   
}
```